# Macro to automate the next month and year based on previous sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro tasked to copy & paste a hidden sheet, enter month and year in a specific cell (based on entered value from previous sheet. I'm currently having issues doing this as the cell from which I obtain (read) my data from contains a month and a year. I have this code so far (given to me by a very helpful community member of stackoverflow):

```
NextMonth = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(DateValue("1/" & Range("A1") & "/" & Year(Date))) + 1, 1), "mmmm")
```

The code works fine if A1 only contains a month. Any ideas how to read in, for example, only "February" although the cell contain "February 2019" and use it with the formula above to get March? With it, I will store the month in a variable "A" and store the year using " B = Year(Now())" in another one. Finally I will assign it to a cell on the desired sheet with " = A & B"

Any thoughts?
Regards,
Alex

Notice: Code the current (actual) month is not of interest. Also, I have the code to automate the first sheet where the code asks the user for input of the month and years.

Comment: When the cell contains "February 2019", is that a text string or an Excel date, which is formatted to be shown as `mmmm yyyy`?

Comment: My apologies, it is a text string

Comment: and yes. That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below allows :
1. the month number
2. the month spelled out
2. a combination of the two points above

In other words, the code would accept the following cell values

- "February" and "February 2019"
- "1" and "1 2019"

```
Sub newmonth()
Dim datecell As Range
Dim d As Variant
Dim newdate As Date

Set datecell = Sheet1.Range("D21")

If IsDate(datecell) Then
    d = datecell
Else
    d = datecell & " " & Year(Now())
End If

newdate = DateAdd("m", 1, d)

Debug.Print Format(newdate, "mmmm yyyy")
'Alternatively, you could put this value in another cell
'Sheet2.Range("A1").Value = Format(newdate, "mmmm yyyy")

End Sub
```

Make sure you tweak the references so that they match your workbook configuration

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: Glad to have helped @Alexander. If an answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the check button right below the downvote button. I see you have a lot of unaccepted answers on your questions :)

Comment: oh I have missed that entirely, I will make sure to do this in the future (and to do the same for my previous questions). Thank you for letting me know